# PCA methods, color function "slplot" showing error?

Tags: r

using "pcaMethods" library I'm trying to plot the PCA using slplot function, color parameter "scol", showing error ? But able to plot using "col" parameter. Suggestions!

> slplot(odorPCAmethods,scoresLoadings = c(T,T),scol = df12class)
>
> Error in text.default(x = c(2.62325023594365, 2.22315995114701,
> 1.08548465511224,  :    invalid color specification In addition: Warning messages: 1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv,
> handler) :   display list redraw incomplete 2: In
> doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :   invalid
> graphics state 3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv,
> handler) :   invalid graphics state

Comment: Without your data or even some description of objects `odorPCAmethods` and `df12class` there is no way to answer your question. Provide reproducible data that illustrates the problem and all of the code needed to generate the error.

Comment: I correct the syntax, working fine.